# Tizen Native Wearable Cannot Launch Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

I am trying to deploy my Tizen Wearable 2.3.2 native app onto a Samsung Gear S3 connected over WiFi. I am running Tizen Studio 1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have previously successfully ran my app multiple times on the emulator and on the same watch, however now when I try to run the app, I get a pop-up window saying

> 'Launching MyApp Debug' has encountered a problem.
>
> Cannot launch application.

Upon clicking on the Details button, I get

```
Cannot launch application.
    java.io.IOException
```

The full console output of the run attempt is

```
Launching the Tizen application...
# If you want to see the detailed information,
# please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences and check the log file in '/home/rytse/tizen-studio-data/ide/logs/ide-20170804_153529.log'.

[Deploying the package...]
    RDS: On
pkg_type [rpm]  pkgid [org.example.myapp]   name [myapp]    version [1.0.0]
Pkgid: org.example.myapp is already Terminated
spend time for pkgcmd is [321]ms
cmd_ret:0
Archive:  /opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp/org.example.myapp.zip
  inflating: /opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp/author-signature.xml  
  inflating: /opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp/signature1.xml  
cmd_ret:0
[RDS] Pushing file "/home/rytse/workspace/MyApp/org.example.myapp.zip" to "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp/org.example.myapp.zip" in target...
[RDS] Pushing file "/home/rytse/workspace/MyApp/.rds_delta" to "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp/.rds_delta" in target...
start process (update)
.
end process (fail)
processing result : FATAL_ERROR [61] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [791]ms
cmd_ret:61
[RDS] Cannot partially upload or reinstall
[Creating the package...]
    Created the package: /home/rytse/workspace/MyApp/Debug/org.example.myapp-1.0.0-arm.tpk
[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: /home/rytse/workspace/MyApp/Debug/org.example.myapp-1.0.0-arm.tpk -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp
[Installing the package...]
    Uninstalling the package...
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.myapp-1.0.0-arm.tpk
start process (install)
...
end process (ok)
spend time for pkgcmd is [5022]ms
cmd_ret:0
    Installed the package: Id(org.example.myapp), Version(1.0.0)
[Running the application...]
... launch failed
(22.441 sec)
```

So far I have tried:

- Pinging the watch (ping successful)
- Disconnecting and reconnecting to the watch
- Clean building signed package
- Clearing and re-generating my Samsung certificates
- Deleting and re-creating the run configuration
- Cloning a working version of my app into a different directory

Based on this, I think the problem is not project-specific. I think it is probably either a global Tizen Studio configuration issue or a problem with my connection to the watch. However, I have not been able to find any other reports of a `java.io.IOException` in Tizen Studio runs online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you install any app in your gear device?

Comment: No, I could not run any app on my device from that computer.

However, I successfully deployed my app from a different computer, so it would seem that this is a problem with my Tizen Studio installation.

I probably could just reinstall Tizen Studio on my computer, however I am curious what was causing the problem.

Comment: Before re-installation, you may try adjusting time & date of your gear device according to dev. PC and regenerate certificate after that. I guess, it can be a certificate issue.

Comment: I cleared my certificates and reinstalled and I can run from Tizen Studio again. Thanks for the help!